# Regular Expression to validate email: illegal character

Tags: javascript

Doing form validation using Jquery without plugins, they're easy enough to use. Trying to teach myself regular expressions and at a wall.

```
var email = $('#email').val();

// Validate email address

// Regular expression to match email address:
var emailReg = \S+@\S+;

if(email.match(emailReg)) {
    // Pass
}
else {
    // Fail
    $('#email').css("background","yellow");
    var counter2 = setTimeout("$('#email').css('background','white')", 3000);
    return false;
}
```

I know it's the worlds simplest regular expression, just trying to get functionality and I'll get more sophisticated later.

Keep getting SyntaxError: illegal character \S (here) +@S+

Don't understand why.  Have searched this site and tried dozens always with console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/` around it.

```
var emailReg = /\S+@\S+/;
               ^       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your regex in forwardslashes like so:

```
var emailReg = /\S+@\S+/;
```

This way it knows it's a regex object, instead of just random operators put together

You could also do:

```
var emailReg = new RegExp("\S+@\S+");
```

This method is useful if you aren't just writing a static regex (eg. getting the regex from user input)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are enclosed in forward slashes in js.  Try 
var emailReg = /\S+@\S+/;